# Open a file in another directory with the C++ fstream class

Tags: c++

When I run my code with arguments I can't read the file when it is in another directory, like this.

In the console

```
./exit first/data.dat second/data.dat
```

The code is:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  const char *In1 = argv[1];
  const char *In2 = argv[2];

  ifstream fp1;
  ifstream fp2;

  fp1.open(In1);
  fp2.open(In2);

  if(!fp1 || !fp2){
     printf("Error");
  }
  ...

}
```

Also, when the arguments are files in the same directory as the exececutable works flawlessly, like this:

```
./exit data1.dat data2.dat
```

I have tried with different argument format, for example:

```
./exit first\data.dat second\data.dat
./exit first//data.dat second//data.dat
./exit first\\data.dat second\\data.dat
./exit .first/data.dat .second/data.dat
./exit ..first/data.dat ..second/data.dat
./exit ../first/data.dat ../second/data.dat
./exit ..//first//data.dat ..//second//data.dat
```

Etc.

Is something wrong with `fstream` or is the way I give the arguments or something different?

Comment: Unrelated: Naming your program `exit` probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: do you have permission to these files you are trying to access? The paths you have mentioned are not equal either

Comment: @nakiya yes, i have the permission to read and write those files, and if you are referring to the `./exit data1.dat data2.dat` is just an example, because i can't name two file equals in the same directory

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ some unrelated, but for the purpose of an example, it works

Comment: Which platform are you on?  The names with backslashes won't work on Unix-based systems. Some of the names with slashes are OK on Unix systems, but some won't work.  The names with `.` or `..` shown won't work, though `./first/data.dat` should work.

Comment: Have you printed the names from within the program?  Maybe the names your program is seeing are not the names you think it should be seeing.  Certainly, it is something to check.  You could lose `In1` and `In2` and write `ifstream fp1(argv[1]); ifstream fp2(argv[2]);`, could you not?  You should also check that `argc >= 3` before using `argv[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I put this as an answer. But answers are formatted better than comments.

Anyways, use perror() to give you an indication of what the problem may be...something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE * pFile;
  pFile=fopen ("unexist.ent","rb");
  if (pFile==NULL)
    perror ("The following error occurred");
  else
    fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

perror() will print whatever error found by the libc functions. So, if you have a permission problems or file path problems it will be printed out.